# Json.Net PopulateObject Appending list rather than setting value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am using Json.Net for .Net 4.5 and when using populate object on the following object it increments the List's with the content of the json rather than setting its value.

**Json.Net**

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(string, object)
```

**Class**

```
class MySettingSubClass
{
    public List<string> MyStringList1 = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three"}
}

class MySetting
{
    public string MyString = "MyString";
    public int MyInt = 5;
    public MySettingSubClass MyClassObject = new MySettingSubClass();
    public List<string> MyStringList2 = new List<string>{"one", "two", "three"};
}
```

When they initially load, all is correct, however reloading from JSON both MyStringLists are duplicated `"one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "three"`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should tell Json.Net to replace the arrays, like this:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};


JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jasonString, myObject, serializerSettings)
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the same `ObjectCreationHandling` option is available on `JsonPropertyAttribute`, allowing just one property to have the effect: `[JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]`

Comment: Would be nice if they had a `ObjectCreationHandling.Merge` option. For a list, we need a way to replace existing elements that match, and add new elements if they do not.