# Deserializing json to C# list with existing items

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the following classes:

```
class Report {

    public Report() {
        this.Fields=new List<Field>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public IList<Field> Fields { get; private set; }
}

class Field {

    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public Guid Identfier { get;set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

and the following test method set up:

```
var report = new Report();
report.Fields.Add(new Field { Identifier = new Guid("26a94eab-3d50-4330-8203-e7750abaa060"), Name = "Field 1" });
report.Fields.Add(new Field { Identifier = new Guid("852107db-b5d1-4344-9f71-7bd90b96fec0"), Name = "Field 2" });

var json = "{\"fields\":[{\"identifier\":\"852107db-b5d1-4344-9f71-7bd90b96fec0\",\"name\":\"name changed\"},{\"identifier\":\"ac424aff-22b5-4bf3-8232-031eb060f7c2\",\"name\":\"new field\"}]}";

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, report);

Assert.IsTrue(report.Fields.Count == 2, "The number of fields was incorrect.");
```

How do I get JSON.Net to know that the field with identifier "852107db-b5d1-4344-9f71-7bd90b96fec0" should apply to the existing field with the same identifier?

Also, is it possible to get JSON.Net to remove items that do not exist within the given JSON array, (specifically the field with identifier "26a94eab-3d50-4330-8203-e7750abaa060" should be removed because it does not exist in the given json array.

If there is a way to manually code or override the way that JSON analyses a list then that would be better because I could write the code to say "this is the item you need" or "use this newly created item" or just "don't do anything to this item because I have removed it".  Anyone know of a way I can do this please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is the `json` string from? Could you simply use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject<T>` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`and compare the elements within?

Comment: I currently am doing that, but I've got many, many objects and sub-objects like this and I'm doing them all manually at the moment and it would be better if there was an automated way for me to just say "here's the key for this item, match it and update it or lose it or create if it doesn't exist".  Maybe what I'm asking is for JSON to provide CRUD in some way to list elements.  If I have to code it I'm fine with that, but coding this once is better and faster than coding every single object I have left to do.

Comment: If you deserialize the object into a List<Field> then the `IEnumerable` extension methods provide a very convenient way of doing this. Would be more readable too, imho.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270266/json-net-populateobject-appending-list-rather-than-setting-value

Answer (score 8):

You can use the option [`ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm).

You can do this for your entire data model using serializer settings, as is shown in [Json.Net PopulateObject Appending list rather than setting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270266/json-net-populateobject-appending-list-rather-than-setting-value):

```
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, report, serializerSettings);
```

Or, you can set the option on the [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) attribute you are already using if you don't want to do this universally:

```
class Report
{
    public Report()
    {
        this.Fields = new List<Field>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("fields", ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]
    public IList<Field> Fields { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't really work when I have a guid that is say value "x" (for simplicity) to apply its json values to the object with guid "x".  I need to say the key to replacing/updating is the identifier field.

Comment: @Anupheaus - it has been a long time since I looked at this.  You want to remove entries in the old list that don't have a corresponding entry in the new list, and replace entries in the old list that do have corresponding entries in the new list.  Doesn't that mean that all entries in the old list get replaced with the new?  If not, could you make a quick unit test that shows what's wrong?  My code passes the test in your question.