# TrackingMode in disconnected application

Tags: codefluent

I'm using CFE with AngularJS front-end and WebApi Controllers;
There's a screen where I have parent-children relationship;

**EntityA** has many **EntityB** which also has many **EntityC**;
I set up Before Update and Before Delete cascade for my objects in the model.

My use case is so that user can edit EntityA, and possibly delete one EntityB that have been previously stored in DB.
I can't have my application to replicate this change correctly. My aim is to drive this replication by sending the full content to the server (new or edited EntityA, updated, created and deleted EntityB and so on for children).

I tried sending the entityState attribute for EntityB (CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.ToBeDeleted) to the server but no luck. The entity state of EntityB is considered as Unchanged upon Save() method.

I read also about the trackingMode that can be changed, but I'm not sure if it would fit my need ? https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_EVT_EN_PropertyChanged.html

Shall I consider changing TrackingMode for an disconnected application ? 
Is there any way to have the client to delete a child that has other children ?

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: I noticed that NewtonSoft doesn't set my collection property but rather load data from DB by calling the getter. Defining the configuration key "hasSet=true" in the model would anyway have no effect on deserialization time before entering my webapi controller.

Comment: If you set `cascadeSave="After"` on the relationship and the value of `EntityState` is `ToBeDeleted`, the instance will be deleted. You can look at `EntityA.Save`, there should be a call to `entityBs.SaveAll()` which will save or delete the records depending of their states. One issue you may have with Json.net is that by default is reuse collection instances instead of replacing them. You may need to change this configuration: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270266/json-net-populateobject-appending-list-rather-than-setting-value>

Comment: It does work even though I noticed that EntityB wouldn't get populated neither by property entityA nor entityAId. EntityC would correctly get populated by entityB and entityBId values. I had to manually set entityAId in my EntityB in order to get it saved correctly.